# Comparing Cell Phone plans c++

Tags: c++

I'm new here. Sorry if I'm not posting correctly. My program is comparing cell phone plans based on minutes. I want to know how I can compare plans to determine the best plan for the money. I believe I should be using minimum functions for this, but I'm honestly stuck. My code is below. Is it possible to find the minimum value from 3 separate functions? I'm not looking for an answer, but maybe an example or an article how to do so. Thanks!

```
    #include<iostream>

using namespace std;


void companyA();
void companyB();
void CompanyC();

int min(); // I want to use this to find my minimum


int numEmployees;
int avgMin;
double totalCost;
// double bestChoice; Not used yet
int main()
{
    double newMin;

    cout << "Please enter number of employees." << endl;
    cin >> numEmployees;

    cout << "Please enter average minutes used by each employee. " << endl;
    cin >> avgMin;


    if (numEmployees < 0)
    {
        cout << "Incorrect value. Please enter positive number of employees." << endl;
        cin >> numEmployees;
    }
     else if (avgMin < 0)
    {
        cout << "Incorrect value. Please enter positive number of minutes. " << endl;
        cin >>  avgMin;
    }

    cout << "\nStandard Packages" << endl;
    cout << "Company A: For $29.99 per month, 450 minutes are included. Additional minutes are $0.35 per minute." << endl;
    cout << "Company B: For $49.99 per month, 900 minutes are provided. Additional minutes are $0.30 per minute." << endl;
    cout << "Company C: For $59.99 per month, unlimited minutes are provided." << endl;

    companyA();
    companyB();
    companyC();
    cout << "\nBased on the number of employees and average minutes used, " << x << "is the best choice." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void companyA()
{
    if (avgMin <= 450)
    {
        totalCost = 29.99*numEmployees;
        cout << "\nCompany A will cost an $" << totalCost << " a month for " << numEmployees << " employee(s)." << endl;
    }
    else if (avgMin > 450)
    {
        totalCost = (avgMin-450)*0.35+29.99;
        cout << "\nCompany A will cost an $" << totalCost << " a month for " << numEmployees << " employee(s)." << endl;

    }
}

void companyB()
{
    if (avgMin <= 900)
    {
        totalCost = 49.99*numEmployees;
        cout << "Company B will cost an $" << totalCost << " a month for " << numEmployees << " employee(s)." << endl;
    }
    else if (avgMin > 900)
    {
        totalCost = (avgMin - 900)*0.30 + 49.99;
        cout << "Company B will cost an $" << totalCost << " a month for " << numEmployees << " employee(s)." << endl;
    }
}

void companyC()
{
        totalCost = 59.99*numEmployees;
        cout << "Company C will cost an $" << totalCost << " a month for " << numEmployees << " employee(s)." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, Create functions that return characteristics of each company by value (`double` or something) and don't print them. Then, use values returned by these functions to compare.

Comment: Alternative way on Linux: use `fork()` to create child process, use `pipe()` and `dup2()` to make communication channel between the parent and child, have the child do the calculation, and parent parse the child's output and do the comparison.

Comment: Your company should consider investing in a spreadsheet program.

Comment: MikeCAT, so I should be using something like 'return result' to compare, right?

Comment: Honestly, I'm really confused. Is there an example code anyone could send me? Instead of using 3 functions, I put them into 1. How can I find the minimum based on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for.

```
void minimum(double numEmployees, double avgMin);
double minimumCompany(double x, double y, double z);

void minimum(double numEmployees, double avgMin)
{
    double totalCostA, totalCostB, totalCostC, minimumTotal;
    string choice;

    if (avgMin <= 450)
    {
        totalCostA = 29.99 * numEmployees;
        cout << "\nCompany A will cost an $" << totalCostA << " a month for " << numEmployees << " employee(s)." << endl;
    }
    else if (avgMin > 450)
    {
        totalCostA = (avgMin - 450) * 0.35 + 29.99;
        cout << "\nCompany A will cost an $" << totalCostA << " a month for " << numEmployees << " employee(s)." << endl;
    }

    if (avgMin <= 900)
    {
        totalCostB = 49.99*numEmployees;
        cout << "Company B will cost an $" << totalCostB << " a month for " << numEmployees << " employee(s)." << endl;
    }
    else if (avgMin > 900)
    {
        totalCostB = (avgMin - 900)*0.30 + 49.99;
        cout << "Company B will cost an $" << totalCostB << " a month for " << numEmployees << " employee(s)." << endl;
    }

    totalCostC = 59.99*numEmployees;
    cout << "Company C will cost an $" << totalCostC << " a month for " << numEmployees << " employee(s)." << endl;

    minimumTotal = minimumCompany(totalCostA, totalCostB, totalCostC);

    if (minimumTotal == totalCostA)
    {
        choice = "Company A";
    }
    else if (minimumTotal == totalCostB)
    {
        choice = "Company B";
    }
    else
    {
        choice = "Company C";
    }

    cout << "\nBased on the number of employees and average minutes used, " << choice << " is the best choice." << endl;

}

double minimumCompany(double x, double y, double z)
{
    double minimum = x;

    if (y < minimum ) { 
        minimum = y;
    }

    if (z < minimum) { 
        minimum = z;
    } 

    return minimum;
}

int main()
{
    double numEmps, averageMin;
    bool isValid = true;

    while (isValid)
    {
        cout << "Please enter number of employees." << endl;
        cin >> numEmps;

        cout << "Please enter average minutes used by each employee. " << endl;
        cin >> averageMin;
        if ((numEmps < 0))
        {
            cout << "Please enter number of employees. " << endl;
            cin >> numEmps;
            isValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isValid = false;
        }

        if ((averageMin < 0))
        {
            cout << "Please enter average minutes used by each employee. " << endl;
            cin >> numEmps;
            isValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isValid = false;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nStandard Packages" << endl;
    cout << "Company A: For $29.99 per month, 450 minutes are included. Additional minutes are $0.35 per minute." << endl;
    cout << "Company B: For $49.99 per month, 900 minutes are provided. Additional minutes are $0.30 per minute." << endl;
    cout << "Company C: For $59.99 per month, unlimited minutes are provided." << endl;

    minimum(numEmps, averageMin);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```